# How to show two pictures in one cell in Jupyter Notebook? (matplotlib) (python)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter

[image: coffee]

[image: horse]

As a beginner, can someone please help me with this? Is there any way to show both pictures in a single cell's output? My output could only display one picture. Thank you for your time and attention!

Here is my code:

```
from skimage import data
image_coffee = data.coffee()
image_horse = data.horse()
fig = plt.figure(dpi=100)
plt.imshow(image_coffee)
plt.imshow(image_horse)
```

Comment: I suggest to use subplots to do so, e.g. see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159436/multiple-figures-in-a-single-window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it (without getting into lots of the inner-workings of Jupyter notebooks), it to use two matplotlib `Axes` in one plot. Then you show one image in each of these:

```
from skimage import data
image_coffee = data.coffee()
image_horse = data.horse()
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 8))  # one row of Axes, two columns = 2 plots
```

The `axs` variables is a list containing the two `Axes`, so just access each one and plot your image on it like this:

```py
axs[0].imshow(image_coffee)
axs[1].imshow(image_horse)
```

If the plots don't pop automatically, either run `plt.show()` or make sure your notebook has executed `%matplotlib inline` in a cell.

Comment: Thank you for the help!